# Cannot add database to an Asp.Net application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, solution, mdf, solution-explorer

I'm unable to add an mdf database file by right clicking on the project name and clicking on "Add->New Item->SQL Server Database".

It gives me the following error...

**

> Connections to SQL Server files
>   (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express
>   2005 to function properly.  Please
>   verify the installation of the
>   component or download from the URL: 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=49251

**

- I'm using SQL server 2008 enterprise
  edition ...but I installed it with
  the instance name as SQLEXPRESS since
  some applications expect it.
- I've uninstalled SQL SERVER 2005 express

Any ideas why and what I should do to correct this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specifying the instance name as SQLEXPRESS in the Instance name won't trick the system into thinking that you actually have the express version installed, so our first bullet point would not help.

Your second point says you uninstalled SQL Server 2005 Express, which is the opposite of what you need to do.

Did you ever have the true Express edition?  (Not the Developer edition that installs with Visual Studio, but the actual SQL Server 2005 Express edition downloaded from the link you posted)?

***Edit - Added***

I see that the link takes you to the 2008 Express edition, not 2005.  I would try going and getting the 2005 install from here instead:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/previous/register.aspx

Comment: Do I need SQL expression edition when I have the full version of SQLserver enterprise 2008 installed?

Comment: I believe that the auto attach ability is restricted to express editions, although you can change the named instance name in tool -> options -> Database(?).  I've had good experience with both 2005 and 2008 express editions.

Comment: I've changed that in tools->options-Database tools->DataConnections

Comment: I haven't used the 2008 edition, so I don't know if that will work or not, so I would bow to Rob's experience on this one, but I am 99% sure he is right - you truly do need the Express edition.

Comment: I installed SQL SERVER  2005 EXPRESS back now. 
Microsoft never mentioned that SQL server express has featurs that enterprise doesn't have.